# Azure OAuth: Unable to programmatically create app with admin consent for permissions

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an Azure AD app for OAuth and trying to assign permissions to it. The app is getting created successfully but I am not seeing permissions assigned correctly.

The following are the steps I am following to create the app.

1. Got the access token using device code flow. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code)
2. Created app using the following piece of C# code

   ```cs
   public async Task CallPostWebApiAndProcessResultAsync(string webApiUrl, string accessToken, string body, Action<JObject> processResult)
   {
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
       {
           var defaultRequetHeaders = HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
           if (defaultRequetHeaders.Accept == null || !defaultRequetHeaders.Accept.Any(m => m.MediaType == "application/json"))
           {
               HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
           }
           defaultRequetHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

           HttpContent postContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
           HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.PostAsync(webApiUrl, postContent);
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               JObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
               processResult(result);
           }
           else
           {
               // Error
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Parameters to the above function are as follows:

   - `webAPIUrl` is : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications"
   - `body` is : `"{ \"displayName\": \"App with permissions in tenant\", \"requiredResourceAccess\": [ { \"resourceAppId\": \"00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000\", \"resourceAccess\": [ { \"id\": \"75359482-378d-4052-8f01-80520e7db3cd\", \"type\": \"Role\" }, { \"id\": \"62a82d76-70ea-41e2-9197-370581804d09\", \"type\": \"Role\" } ]}]}"`

I can verify that the app is getting created successfully but I am not able to see permissions assigned to it successfully.

I am trying to allocate Graph API permissions *Files.ReadWrite.All* and *Group.ReadWrite.All*. These permissions are also getting added but their status is "Unable to determine status". Admin consent is not automatically granted.

While getting the device code I log in using tenant admin creds so I am not sure what more is required here.

Unfortunately not able to find much on this on the net. Please let me know if anyone has any idea about this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2bp3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting **requiredResourceAccess** only serves to declare what permission your app *requests* (or *requires*, depending on the flow). This is *not* the same thing as actually granting those permissions. From the documentation for the **requiredResourceAccess** property of an [application](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0) object:

> [requiredResourceAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/requiredresourceaccess?view=graph-rest-1.0) collection 
> Specifies resources that this application requires access to and the set of OAuth permission scopes and application roles that it needs under each of those resources. This pre-configuration of required resource access drives the consent experience. Not nullable.

One approach to granting the permissions requested by an application is to use the interactive tenant-wide consent URL to get prompted to grant the permissions, as described in [Grant tenant-wide admin consent to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent).

Alternatively, you can use Microsoft Graph to grant these permissions.

Application permissions are app roles. To grant application permissions, you must [create an app role assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in the **appRoleAssignedTo** collection of the API's service principal:

1. Ensure there exists a service principal for the client application. If it doesn't (e.g. because you only just created the application), then [create the service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Let `{principal-id}` be the **id** of the client app's **servicePrincipal** object.
2. Retrieve the service principal for the resource application (e.g. the API, in this case). Let `{resource-id}` be the **id** of the resource app's **servicePrincipal** object.
3. Look up the **id** of the app role you wish to grant. In this case you already have this (you used it in the application object's **requiredResourceAccess**), but you can also look it up in the **appRoles** collection of the resource app's **servicePrincipal** object. Let `{app-role-id}` be the **id** of the **appRole** you want to grant.
4. Create the app role assignment:

   ```
   POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{resource-id}/appRoleAssignedTo

   {
     "principalId": "{principal-id}",
     "resourceId": "{resource-id}",
     "appRoleId": "{app-role-id}"
   }
   ```
5. Repeat step 4 for every app role (application permission) for that API.

Instead of constructing all these requests manually, I recommend using the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/sdks/sdks-overview).

---

**WARNING**
By granting an app application permissions to Microsoft Graph, you may be giving the application very privileged access to your organization and the organization's data. Be sure you fully understand the implications before you do this.

Comment: i want to add User administrator role to my application for   deleting the  users in ad b2c through graph api. I created an  app and service principal using step 1 and 2. But in my  service principle  there is  no role assignment id  present.it look like     "appRoleAssignmentRequired": false,
 "appRoles": [],

how do i get teh role id ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe granting admin consent is a separate step that needs to be executed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent